# Transposing a long row into a long column using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to working with the Pandas, however, I have a question that I hope makes sense to seasoned Python developers familiar with Pandas.

I am reading in a csv file from Microsoft Excel using the Python Pandas library in which the data is organized into long rows. The beginning of each row contains a date followed by subsequent values of measurements:

```
Date        A1             A2              A3               A1001
1/1/2000, measurement 1, measurement 2, measurement 3, to measurement 1000.
```

I wish to transpose each row into three new columns consisting of a "date" column, a "data" column, and a "location" column which will be kept blank for now.

Once January 1st is complete, it will start all over again with 1/2/2000. These will be tremendously long columns, I know. I need it this way to upload into a database versus incredibly lengthy rows.

All of this will be written to a new csv file that is transposed from the original file.

I have attempted to select the first row using "iloc." I am not quite sure where to go from here.

Thank you for your help.

The code below is my attempt at formatting just one row before I do it on all of them.

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file')

#select individual row
first_row = df.iloc[0]

#convert to dataframe
first_row = pd.DataFrame(data=df.iloc[0])

#transpose?
first_row.stack()

#test the output
print(first_row)

#reformatted_df.to_csv('csv_output_file')
```

Each row contains 1000 cells with numerical measurements.

Instead of having one date on one row and all the values associated with it, I would like three columns that look like this:

```
Date     Data           Location
1/1/2000 Measurement 1...
1/1/2000 Measurement 2...
1/1/2000 Measurement 3...
1/1/2000 Measurement 1000
etc.

The column continues for 1/2/2000:
Date      Data           Location
1/2/2000 Measurement 1...
1/2/2000 Measurement 2...
1/2/2000 Measurement 3...
1/2/2000 Measurement 1000
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get what you're looking for is to set the date as your index and use `.unstack()` to convert the columns to rows:

```
In [42]: d = {'date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03']}

In [43]: for i in range(1, 1001):
    ...:     d['A{:03}'.format(i)] = ['measurement {}'.format(i)] * 3
    ...:

In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
         date           A001           A002        ...                    A998             A999             A1000
0  2000-01-01  measurement 1  measurement 2        ...         measurement 998  measurement 999  measurement 1000
1  2000-01-02  measurement 1  measurement 2        ...         measurement 998  measurement 999  measurement 1000
2  2000-01-03  measurement 1  measurement 2        ...         measurement 998  measurement 999  measurement 1000

[3 rows x 1001 columns]

In [46]: long_df = df.set_index('date').unstack().to_frame('Data').swaplevel().sort_index()

In [47]: long_df['Location'] = None

In [48]: long_df
Out[48]:
                            Data Location
date
2000-01-01 A001    measurement 1     None
           A002    measurement 2     None
           A003    measurement 3     None
           A004    measurement 4     None
           A005    measurement 5     None
...                          ...      ...
2000-01-03 A995  measurement 995     None
           A996  measurement 996     None
           A997  measurement 997     None
           A998  measurement 998     None
           A999  measurement 999     None

[3000 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can then get rid of the old column names and get back an autonumbered index with `reset_index()` and `drop()`:

```
In [49]: long_df.reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
Out[49]:
            date             Data Location
0     2000-01-01    measurement 1     None
1     2000-01-01    measurement 2     None
2     2000-01-01    measurement 3     None
3     2000-01-01    measurement 4     None
4     2000-01-01    measurement 5     None
...          ...              ...      ...
2995  2000-01-03  measurement 995     None
2996  2000-01-03  measurement 996     None
2997  2000-01-03  measurement 997     None
2998  2000-01-03  measurement 998     None
2999  2000-01-03  measurement 999     None

[3000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file')

# transpose date and data
new_df = df.transpose()

# rename the column names
new_df.columns = ['Date', 'Data']

# now if you want to add a new column called location and keep it blank 
new_df['location'] = new_df.apply(lambda x:"" , axis=1)
```